# Template class in shared library only working with implicit AND explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries, instantiation

I have two classes that are together in a shared library.

```
--- foo.h
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    Foo();
    void doSomething(void);
...
};

--- foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

template <class T>
Foo:Foo()
{
};

template <class T>
void Foo::doSomething(void)
{
};

// Here I put the explicit/implicit instantiations (see below)

--- bar.h
template <class T>
class Bar
{
...
};

--- bar.cpp
template <class T>
class Bar
{
...
};

template class Bar<int>;
```

And a main function that uses those:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main(void)
{
    Foo<Bar<int> > foobar; // Or Foo<int> foobar; for version 5
    foobar.doSomething();
}
```

Now, to make that work I want to instantiate Foo. There are 5 ways I tried to do that:

Version 1: Explicit instantiation (doesn't work)

```
template class Foo<Bar<int> >;
```

Version 2: Implicit instantiation light (doesn't work)

```
void dummy(void){Foo<Bar<int> > foobar;}
```

Version 3: Implicit instantiation (doesn't work)

```
void dummy(void){Foo<Bar<int> > foobar; foobar.doSomething();}
```

Version 4: Implicit AND explicit instantiation (works)

```
template class Foo<Bar<int> >;
void dummy(void){Foo<Bar<int> > foobar; foobar.doSomething();}
```

Version 5: Explicit instantiation with non-templated type (works)

```
template class Foo<int>; // Works, if you change the main as well
```

Why does only version 4 work for `Foo<Bar<int> >`? Why does `Foo<int>` work, but `Foo<Bar<int> >` not? For the not working ones I get 'undefined reference' errors. The code is very simplified and it doesn't happen with code that is that much simplified, but it is quite hard to break down the code to the point where it's no longer working because it's embedded in a rather complex project. I am mostly looking for hints here what could possibly cause this.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is "not working", where are you getting 'undefined reference' errors? You can't just put template body into cpp and make shared library of it.

Comment: I get the undefined reference for the constructor of ’Foo’. I know, that's why I wanted to use explicit instantiation, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to figure it out. The problem was the compilation order. `Bar<int>` got explicitly instantiated, but apparently that happened after the explicit instantiation of `Foo<Bar<int> >` which somehow prevented it from being instantiated. Adding another `template class Bar<int>;` right before `template class Foo<Bar<int> >;` in the same module solved the issue.